# constructing a loop using powershell and having access to all elements

Tags: powershell

I have got a csv file with the following columns/data.

```
name,gender,age
tom,Male,50
jack,Male,60
jill,Female,45
```

I am trying to construct a foreach loop where I can reference the columns `name`,`gender`,`age` and obtain the values. Similar to a cursor within the database world. Foreach only allows me access to say one column `name`, I would like to loop through each row, get the values for tom's name, gender and age.

Comment: Using `Import-Csv` and a loop you can access the single values for the individual columns by their name?! ‍♂️ What would you actually like to do with the values? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show us your foreach loop.

Comment: @learner  Do you actually ignore the comments on purpose to finally get someone to post an answer for you? ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields become named properties of each row.  If your foreach loop pulls out the data row by row,  you access the fields like named properties.  The following code just does something stupid with each field, but you get the idea.

```
$people = Import-Csv MyFile.csv

Foreach ($person in $people) {
    $name = $person.name
    $gender = $person.gender
    $age = $person.age

    "Person named $name is of gender $gender and has age $age"
    }
```